# Same image looks different when loaded in imageview and webview

Tags: android, webview, imageview, png

In my app I have an imageview on screen "A" and a webview on screen "B".

On screen "A" I start an sync task in order to download and show a png file into the imageview.

On screen "B" I load some HTML info. in which the link to the same png on screen "A" is included.

The problem is that the same image looks different on both screens. When loaded in the imageview, the png looks way smaller than when it is loaded in the webview.

The height and the width of the imageview are set to wrap_content. There is no additional scaling or something similar.

Why is this happening?

**---EDIT---**

**screen "A" layout**

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background_repeat">



    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**screen "B" layout**

```
    <RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">


                <WebView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/about_us_web_view"
                    />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

**screen "A" asyncTask**

```
private class DownloadLogoTask extends AsyncTask<ImageView, String, Bitmap> {

    private String urlString;

    public DownloadLogoTask(String urlString) {
        this.urlString = urlString;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(ImageView... imageViews) {

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

            if(bitmap != null) {
                return bitmap;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if(result != null) {
            logoImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

**screen "B" usage of the webView**

```
aboutUsWebView.loadData(descriptionStr, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code to the ImageView and the layout wrapping the webview if you want a good answer.

Comment: have u got any sample code?

Comment: i've edited the question

Comment: but what is descriptionStr